# How to read 11mb textfile in php?

Tags: php, file-io

I read 11mb textfile with php:

```
$data_array = array();

$counter = 0;        

while(!feof($fh))  {

    $buffer = fgets($fh, 4096);

    $data_array[$counter] = $buffer;

    $counter++;
}
```

Then I want to use implode function to get all into one variable.

```
$data = implode("",$data_array);
```

But the script does nothing. If I try to store data into one variable during the loop, it takes very long time.
Is there some other way how to do this? I need to have data from 11mb textfile in one variable in php.

Comment: Why do you need to have data from 11mb textfile in one variable?

Comment: this is what happens really when you are trying to read files > 10mb. i think there is no way to read faster.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, you're trying to reinvent the wheel. There is already function in PHP for that:

```
$data = file_get_contents($filename)
```

Second, if you're not getting any results, check the memory and time limits you have set in `php.ini`.

Comment: ...and, since it sounds like its falling over due to running out of memory, do check your error reporting config

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `$data = file_get_contents('filename');`?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to make the text file smaller parts if you can. Also there's execution limit in php.ini file 30 seconds should be default after which the script is terminated.

Comment: By default there is no limit when the scripts is called from the command line.